# Sum to infinity of geometric sequences (simultaneous equation)

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I tried to eliminate a:

$76-76r=a$

$36-36r^3=a$

I ended up with $40-76r+36r^3=0$

I was unsure on how to proceed so I checked the mark scheme and I should have ended up with a quadratic $9r^2+9r-10=0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your 3rd degree equation obviously has $r=1$ as a solution ($40-76+36=0$), so the left side has $r-1$ as a factor, ideed, it has $4(r-1)$ as a factor. Therefore....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know, $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} ar^j=\frac{a}{1-r}=76$, and $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} ar^{3j}=\frac{a}{1-r^3}=36$.

We have: $\frac{a}{1-r^3}=\frac{a}{(1-r)(r^2+r+1)}=\frac{76}{r^2+r+1}=36$, and from here:

$r^2+r+1=\frac{76}{36}$ which have to solution's $r=\frac{2}{3}$ or $r=\frac{-5}{3}$. the case $r=\frac{-5}{3}$ cant happen because we should have  $|r|\lt 1$ to the series be convergence.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite sum of a geometric sequence with ratio $0 < k < 1$ is and first term $b$ is

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty b\cdot k^i = \dfrac{b}{1-k}$$

Applying this to your problem:

$$\begin{cases}76 = \dfrac{a}{1-r} & \\ 36 = \dfrac{a}{1-r^3} \end{cases}$$

Or, equivalently:

$$*\begin{cases}a = 76(1-r) & \\ a = 36(1-r^3) \end{cases}$$

So:
$$76(1-r) = 36(1-r^3) \Rightarrow 19 = 9\dfrac{1-r^3}{1-r} \Rightarrow 19 = 9(r^2+r+1) \Rightarrow 9r^2 + 9r -10 = 0$$

EDIT: I just realized you can get to the equation marked as $*$ with the two first equations you wrote. Note that since $r < 1$ you can divide both ends by $r-1$ to get to the quadratic equation. Your equation has the same roots as this one and also the root $r = 1$ wich we know can't be possible for a convergent geometric series.

$$4(r-1)(9r^2+9r-10) = 36r^2 - 76r +40$$